# How do I make it so that when I click on the callout button, I get a modal window .sheet - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit, mapkit

When you click on the annotation on the map I have a window pops up with information about the location and callout button, I want when you click on the button to open a modal window, that's how I tried to solve this problem, I try to pass some location values to the new BusStopView modal window, but even the print check "print" doesn't work, and I don't understand what's wrong

```
struct Location: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
    let latitude: Double
    let longitude: Double
    
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    }
}


struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    
    var forDisplay = locations
    @State private var mapRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: ..., longitude: ...), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.2, longitudeDelta: 0.2))
    @Binding var selectedPlace: Location?
    
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
        
        var parent: MapView
        
        init(_ parent: MapView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        /// showing annotation on the map
        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
            
            
            let annotationView = AnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: AnnotationView.ReuseID)
            annotationView.canShowCallout = true
            
            let button = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
            annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = button
            
            return annotationView
        }
        
        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
            if let annotation = view.annotation as? LandmarkAnnotation {
                parent.selectedPlace = annotation.location
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        MapView.Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
            let view = MKMapView()
            view.delegate = context.coordinator
            view.setRegion(mapRegion, animated: false)
            view.mapType = .standard
            
            for annotation in forDisplay {
                view.addAnnotation(annotation)
            }
            
            return view
        }

    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Context) {
        
    }
}


class LandmarkAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    let location: Location
    
    init(location: Location) {
        self.location = location
        self.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude)
        super.init()
    }
}

let clusterID = "clustering"

class AnnotationView: MKMarkerAnnotationView {

static let ReuseID = "cultureAnnotation"

/// setting the key for clustering annotations
    override init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        clusteringIdentifier = clusterID
    }


required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func prepareForDisplay() {
    super.prepareForDisplay()
    displayPriority = .defaultLow
 }
}

struct MapContentView: View {
    
    @State var title = ""
    @State var subtitle = ""
    @State var selectedPlace: Location?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            MapView(selectedPlace: $selectedPlace)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .sheet(item: $selectedPlace) { place in
                    BusStopView(title: place.id, stopnametitle: place.name)
                        .background(Color(red: 0.949, green: 0.949, blue: 0.969))
                        .onAppear {
                            print("BusStopView presented")
                        }
                    
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I am still new to swift development, trying to improvise, but I have stopped at this problem for a very long time

Comment: You have added a button as your call-out accessory view but there is no handler associated with it; no action is taken when you tap the button.